# Is the kernel always loaded in memory once the computer starts?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I am assuming that the answer is yes. But I just want to make sure. I know this can be a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the kernel has to be loaded into memory. Otherwise you get the chicken and egg problem of how to handle page faults when the page fault handler is not in memory (one example). However, parts of the kernel can be pageable and loaded on demand.